# Is cross-entropy loss for MaxEnt models convex? If so, how do I prove it?

Tags: maximum-entropy, cross-entropy, convex

I am trying to prove if cross-entropy loss for MaxEnt models is convex.

My first attempt at approaching this problem is to compute the Hessian matrix of second-order partial derivatives and showing that it is positive semidefinite. However, I am not able to find the second-order partial derivatives.

Comment: Please provide more details on what is a cross-entropy loss and what is a MaxEnt model.

Comment: Do you mean logistic regression?